# Remote ipconfig /release issue with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powercli

I have a powershell script that does an ipconfig /release and /flushdns then a shutdown command for my VMs. I do this before creating a snapshot. The script works but it doesn't work for multiple computers in a CSV because as soon as the ipconfig /release occurs it gets stuck on the same machine and waits for it to reconnect. Is there a way to break the script so that it forces to go to the next machine? It's doing the shutdown as well just not moving onto next machine. Code:

```
$Machines | foreach-object {
    
    write-host $_.MachineName
    
    Get-Service -Computer $_.MachineName -Name CcmExec | Stop-Service
    Get-Service -Computer $_.MachineName -Name CcmExec | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
    Get-Service -Computer $_.MachineName -Name CcmExec
    Invoke-Command -Computer $_.MachineName -ScriptBlock {
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $Using:Username
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Configuration Manager\" | Disable-ScheduledTask
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /flushdns
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /release
    cmd.exe /c shutdown -f -s -t 25
      
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can do `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machines` and remove the `ForEach-Object` part to do all in parallel

Comment: I think you could also chain all the commands like `ipconfig /flushdns && ipconfig /release && shutdown -f -s -t 25`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but couldn't you just `ipconfig /release /flushdns` to knock out one command and do both those at once? Also, since you're putting a 25 second timer on the shutdown command, could you issue that first, and then do your `ipconfig /release /flushdns` in those 25 seconds? That way losing your network connectivity is the last thing you do.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I guess I should've included the entire script, but I'm doing some tasks before the shutdowns like stopping services.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician This does not work because ipconfig /release is what is breaking the script from going onto the next machine. It tries to reconnect to the same computer but doesn't realize it's already disconnected and shutdown to move onto next

Comment: @Jon please amend and provide your entire script. Otherwise Santiago and TheMadTech gave you good answers, We need more information why what they wrote isn't helping.

Comment: In google, you might do the following search and see if anything looks like it will work for you: site:stackoverflow.com "PowerShell" "Stop-Job" "force"

Comment: I've added the entire script

Comment: Once a computer has no ip and is offline (ipconfig /release), you can't wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I was laying down to go to sleep last night, this popped into my head.  Why, how, I don't know!

What happens if you change

```
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /flushdns
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /release
    cmd.exe /c shutdown -f -s -t 25
```

to

```
    cmd.exe /c shutdown -f -s -t 300
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /flushdns
    cmd.exe /c ipconfig /release
```

?

I would think any termination of the remote ran scriptblock would result in the caller continuing on to do other work.

Comment: If this solution works, you might also wrap the Invoke-Command in a Measure-Command to see if a certain server is constantly taking the full 300 seconds for the script to end.  Repeated behavior like that might mean there is a problem that needs to be investigated.

Comment: The 300 seconds may be longer than you want, so again, if this solution works, you might temporarily wrap the two ipconfig statements in a Measure-Command and create a log on each server.  Not sure if the hanging servers will create log entries as the services are killed, but either way, you should be able to identify the longest time for a successful ipconfig, add 20 or so seconds, and make that the new time for shutdown.